# Maui app doesn't work after downloaded from github

Tags: c#, import, maui

[image]

This week, I built a new computer and I installed Visual Studio 2022 community version. I installed all of the packets (included MAUI apps) but I encountered some errors when.

I obviously downloaded project from my github at first. There is a problem because the app doesn't want to compile an run.

I don't know it is dotnet version problem or some else.

I even coped project folder from my old device (where it worked) but it's still same codes.

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: I'v got no .NET 6.0 option in maui on new device. I think, it is a cause. How can I install .net6.0 for maui?

Comment: @BlokerX 1.First in Visual Studio installer, make sure you have installed .NET 6.0 ,see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BADpC.png) And then you can edit the csproj file and then replace net7.0 with net6.0, see this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjUaz.png). Save the csproj file and wait until the dependencies are loaded. In Visual Studio check under the Dependencies node under your project to see the net6.0 targets there now.